# WebPack and react-hot module with babel and ES6 doesn't update page on save

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have some files Typescrypt->ES6->React JSX (ES6)->Webpack (with react-hot and babel),
**react-hot does not refresh page**

One is some sort of code behide *PersonDetailsComponent.cb.js*
(compiled from TypeScript)

```
import * as React from "react/addons";
export default class PersonDetailsComponent_CB extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    }
    //other code
    render() {
        //return React.jsx(`<div>test</div>`);
        //return React.DOM.div(null, this.props.name + " is a " + this.props.role);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then *PersonDetailsComponent.jsx* (because TypeScript compiler can't parse JSX)

```
    import * as React from "react/addons";
    import {default as PersonDetailsComponent_CB} from "../tmp/PersonDetailsComponent.cb.js";

    class PersonDetailsComponent extends PersonDetailsComponent_CB {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
//only render
        render() {
            let a = 1;
            return(
                <div>
                {this.props.name} is  {this.props.role}
                </div>
                );
        }
    }

    export default function Factory(props) {
        "use strict";
        return React.createElement(PersonDetailsComponent, props);
    }
```

Then *index.js* chunk

```
import {default as PersonDetailsComponent}  from "./PersonDetailsComponent.jsx";

React.render(PersonDetailsComponent(
    {name: "Bob", 
    role: "mmm"}),
    document.body);
```

All is OK, but **react-hot does not refresh page** then I edit and save jsx file. For jsx files in ES5 format all is updating.
I'm using webpack and react-hot and babel

```
gulp.task('react:development', function() {
  var wconfig = {
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://'+whost+':'+wport,
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
      path: process.cwd(),
      //contentBase: 'http://'+whost+':'+wport,
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: 'http://'+whost+':'+wport+'/dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
      new dwebpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new dwebpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx?harmony!babel', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx?harmony!babel', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
      ]
    }
  };

  var server = new WebpackDevServer(dwebpack(wconfig), {
    publicPath: wconfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      progress: true
    }
  });

  server.listen(wport, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    gutil.log('Webpack Dev Server started. Compiling...');
  });
});
```

Anybody know this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the mode client-side ? I'm using

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

on the very first client-side file that's been called